# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in (Remote MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cpanel

I have one shared Cpanel Hosting and one My own server with cpanel hosting. I am trying to connect from shared cpanel hosting to my own server for get data from my own server. 
I have added my shared cpanel hosting IP to my server cpanel in remote MySQL section but I am getting above error. I have also added that IP from WHM but not success. I have checked that port 3306 also open. I do not know whats issue.
I have tried below connection type but same error always.

```
$SERVER_NAME = "195.201.XXX.XXX";
$USER_NAME = "MyUserName"; 
$PASSWORD = "MyPass";
$DATABASE = "Mydb";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($SERVER_NAME, $USER_NAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE,"3306");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

I have also tried below code

```
 $SERVER_NAME = "195.201.XXX.XXX";
    $USER_NAME = "MyUserName"; 
    $PASSWORD = "MyPass";
    $DATABASE = "Mydb";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($SERVER_NAME, $USER_NAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
```

But I am getting error like this

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused
```

and in error log like this

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
```

Let me know whats wrong with it and how can I solve it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using your details in the command line?

Comment: I don't know how can I run in command line

Comment: Try running in command line `mysql -uusername -p` and type the password when it prompts

Comment: Are you sure that your local server is indeed using port 3306..if it is MAMP for instance, port 3306 is not the default and also you must have a user in MySQL who is allowed to connect from % (any host) (see manual for details)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs its working fine with command line as You have given. Thanks

Comment: @omar Did you copy and paste straight from your code the values? :) just wanna be 100% sure :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I have tried mysql -uwhatsonl_raj -p and its working fine and showing welcome message.

Comment: Wait another quickie, try ssh into the remote server, see if you get any permission errors